# Bootstrap Pills space at the top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap Pills for a menu and there is a space at the top. I already have spacing removed for the `<li>` but I don't know how to get rid of the space at the top of the very first `<li>`.

```
   .nav-pills > li > a 
    { 
        margin-top: -4px; 
        margin-bottom: -1px; 
    }

    .HomePageMenuContainer
    {    
        background-color: #272b30;  
        border-radius: 8px; 
        border: 5px solid lightgray;  
        padding: 1px;
    }


<div class="HomePageMenuContainer voffset2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked voffset3">
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Collision Repair</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Classic Restoration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

**UPDATE: based on the answer below this is the CSS I to fix it.**

Setting both margin and padding to "0" got rid of the space but also made it go above the border. I just added a little top padding to bring it down to where it needed to be.

```
ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 3px !important;
}
```

Comment: check the `ul`.  It's probably a rogue margin or padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find a solution.

Try using this.

```
ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked.voffset3 {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

This will allow you to remove unnecessary spaces. I just use `!important` because I don't know the main path of the `ul` element.

Comment: Thanks...a couple minor tweaks to that got me fixed. I posted my fix in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
              .nav-pills > li > a 
    { 
        margin-top: -4px; 
        margin-bottom: -1px; 
    }

    .HomePageMenuContainer
    {    
        background-color: #272b30;  
        border-radius: 8px; 
        border: 5px solid lightgray;  
        padding: 1px;
    }

           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
           <div class="HomePageMenuContainer voffset2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked voffset3">
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Collision Repair</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Classic Restoration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

           </body>
           </html>
```

As you can see from the above snippet there is no margin associated with it as mentioned in your question.

Comment: Do you have more css? Please post them to get a complete answer.